# Jenkins PHPUnit bootstrap failing

Tags: php, jenkins, phpunit

When I run PHPUnit on the command line it works fine:

```
$ phpunit --bootstrap Tests/autoload.php Tests/Classes/Database/customer/CreativeTest
PHPUnit 4.1.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.

...

Time: 225 ms, Memory: 12.50Mb

OK (3 tests, 34 assertions)
```

However when I try to run it with Jenkins the bootstrap autoload is apparently failing because it says it can't find the parent class of CreativeTest:

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson3966267216183299087.sh
+ /usr/local/bin/phpunit --bootstrap Tests/autoload.php    Tests/Classes/Database/customer/CreativeTest
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'LPtools\Tests\LPTest' not found in  /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/LPtools_Unit_Tests/workspace/Tests/Classes/Database/customer/CreativeTest.php on line 20
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm a Jenkins novice so any help here would be awesome!

Comment: My guess is that there is something wrong with your autoload function, try manually specifying each file to include in your autoload file. (also you may want to paste the current contents of your autoload and short example of your projects filesystem)

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. My autoloader made an assumption about the file structure external to the repository which obviously wasn't true in Jenkins' workspace.